# how to make two function in same route using symfony 5

Tags: forms, symfony, routes

i would to make two function in same route,
like function index and edit

```
   /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_prospect_index", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function index( ): Response
    
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="app_prospect_edit", methods={"GET", "POST"}) 
     */
    public function edit( ): Response
```

i try :

```
   /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_prospect_index", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request,Prospect $prospect, ProspectRepository      $prospectRepository, Security $security): Response
    {  
         
        $form = $this->createForm(ProspectAffectType::class, $prospect); 
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $prospectRepository->add($prospect, true);
            
            $this->entityManager->persist($prospect);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_prospect_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

       $prospect =  $prospectRepository->findByUserConect($security->getUser()->getId());
            $request->getSession()->set('security', count($prospect) );
        

     
        return $this->render('prospect/index.html.twig', [
            'prospects' => $prospect,
            // 'form' => $form,
             
            
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add requested id condition in this function and render template based on it.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_prospect_index", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ProspectRepository      $prospectRepository, Security $security): Response
    {  
        $prospectId = $request->query->get('id'); 
        if (!empty($prospectId)) {
        $prospect = $entityManager->getRepository(Prospect::class)->find($prospectId);
        $form = $this->createForm(ProspectAffectType::class, $prospect); 
        $form->handleRequest($request);

         if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $prospectRepository->add($prospect, true);
            
            $this->entityManager->persist($prospect);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_prospect_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
         }

        return $this->render('prospect/form.html.twig', [
            'prospects' => $prospect,
            'form' => $form 
        ]);
        }
       $prospect =  $prospectRepository->findByUserConect($security->getUser()->getId());
            $request->getSession()->set('security', count($prospect) );
        
        return $this->render('prospect/index.html.twig', [
            'prospects' => $prospect,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Variable "form" does not exist.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          {{ form_start(form) }}

Comment: @Badrman Ofcourse you have to take twig file separately for both condition :) or you can pass `form` object in `index.html.twig`. I have updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="app_prospect_index", methods={"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function index(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ProspectRepository      $prospectRepository, Security $security): Response
{ 
   $prospect =  $prospectRepository->findByUserConect($security->getUser()->getId());
        $request->getSession()->set('security', count($prospect) );
    

 
    return $this->render('prospect/index.html.twig', [
        'prospects' => $prospect,
        // 'form' => $form,    
        
    ]);
}
  public function edit(Request $request, Prospect $prospect, ProspectRepository $prospectRepository): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ProspectType::class, $prospect);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $prospectRepository->add($prospect, true);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_prospect_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('prospect/edit.html.twig', [
        'prospect' => $prospect,
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```